# How to get list of all folders and files within a drive with their respective paths

Tags: python, cmd

I am trying to get the list of all folders and files (including hidden and operating system files) within a drive. I cannot loop it as each folder has different depth. Is there any command in cmd that lets us see each file and folder within a drive with their absolute paths provided? Thanks.

Comment: tried `os.walk`, `glob.glob`?

Comment: On *nix, the `tree` command does this. edit: oh. `tree` is/was a DOS command. Does it suit your needs? It'd be `tree /f`

Comment: you most certainly can loop.  lots of ways to handle depths including recursion.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I list all files of a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-do-i-list-all-files-of-a-directory)

Answer (score 1):

In the Windows command prompt, you could try [`tree /f`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/tree).

However this might not include hidden files.

Comment: (sorry, away from my Windows machines right now so can't check for myself)

Comment: thanks for your answer, I found my solution for the problem with .walk()